# ノートPCの Windows で macOS の Ctrl+タップのように右クリックしたい

Tags: windows, windows-10

Macbookでは、Ctrlを押しながらタッチパッドをシングルタップすると右クリック出来ます。

Windowsで同じことをすると、ファイルの複数選択となります。
Windowsでmacのこの操作を再現方法はあるのでしょうか？

例えば、Alt+シングルタップで右クリックを行うことはできないのでしょうか？

Shift+F10やアプリケーションキーで右クリックできることは承知していますが、ホームポジションを外さずにマウスカーソルのある位置を右クリックしたいと考えています。
※フォーカスが当たっている箇所の右クリックではありません。

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ちょっと試してみたらこちらの[AutoHotKey](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/home)でカスタマイズ出来るようです。

**「ホームポジションを外さずに」** という条件はキーボード操作の設定なのでクリアしています。
**Ctrl+シングルタップ** という動作でも、「シングルタップ」が「マウスの左クリック」として通知されているなら置き換え可能でしょう。

[MouseClick](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/commands/MouseClick)

> マウスのボタンを押し下げ/押し上げしたり、クリックしたり、ホイールを回したりする
>
> ```
> MouseClick [, WhichButton , X, Y, ClickCount, Speed, D|U, R]
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ```
> 引数名　　　 説明
> WhichButton　どのボタンを操作するか
>              RIGHT
>                   右ボタン
>
> X, Y         クリックする座標。
>              省略時は現在のカーソル位置
>              通常はアクティブウィンドウの左上からの相対座標だが、CoordModeでスクリーン全体での絶対座標に変更できる。
> ```

例えばこんな感じでスクリプトを作っておくと、`Alt`+`k`でマウスの右クリックになりました。

```
!k::
MouseClick,right
```

そして以下のようにすると、`Ctrl`+`マウス左クリック`でマウスの右クリックにできます。

```
^LButton::
MouseClick,right
```

ちなみに`^`の代りに`!`で`Alt`+`マウス左クリック`にしようとしたら、このキーの組み合わせは完全には上書きできないのか、すぐにメニューが閉じてしまい選択できない状況でした。全部が上手く行くって訳ではなさそうですね。
[Mac で右クリックする方法](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT207700)

**「マウスカーソルのある位置を右クリック」** であれば、`MouseClick`処理のデフォルトがそうなっています。例えば追加でそうでは無い特定のウインドウとかさらにその中の何かとかでも、スクリプトの機能で調べて指定出来るでしょう。

---

以下はその他参考情報抜粋

[AutoHotkeyJp](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/home)

> AutoHotkeyはオープンソースで誰でも制限無く利用出来る※1Windowsプラットフォームで動く強力なスクリプトエンジンで、キーボードやマウスをカスタマイズしたり、ウィンドウ操作を自動化したりできます。

[イントロダクション - マウス、ジョイスティック対応](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/Introduction#TOC--2)

> ホットキーには、多機能キーボードの特殊キーなどを含め、ほとんどのキーを使用できる。
> 更に、マウスのボタン(右、左、ホイールボタン、拡張ボタン1,2,ホイールの上下回転)やジョイスティックの各ボタンにも、キーボードと同様に機能の割り当てが行える。

[ホットキー](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/Hotkeys)

> **Windows標準ホットキー**
> Win+EやWin+RなどのWindows標準ホットキーも動作を上書きしたり無効化したり出来る。

[ホットキーの上書きと無効化](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/misc/Override)

> AutoHokteyは他のアプリケーションのホットキーを上書きしたり無効化したりすることが出来る。
> **グローバルなホットキーの上書き**
> アクティブなアプリケーションに関係なく動くホットキーで、 例えばウィンドウズ標準のホットキーの Win+E(エクスプローラ起動)がこれに該当する。

[キーリスト](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/KeyList)

> 制御キー　AppsKey　コンテキストメニューを出すキー。右ALtの隣にあることが多い。

Comment: 質問で求めているのはタッチパッドでの操作であり、こちらの回答に挙げられた AutoHotKey は名前の通りホットキー (キーボード) の操作をカスタマイズするツールです。

Comment: いや、マウスの動きもエミュレート出来るようですが。[MouseClick](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/commands/MouseClick)

Comment: カーソル位置について、紛らわしい表現でしたので修正しました。
「マウスカーソルの位置に対して右クリックしたい」というのが質問内容で、テキストカーソル位置という意味ではありません。

Comment: ではそれに合わせてこちらも修正しておきます。

Answer (score 3):

二本指でタッチパッドをタップするか、右下隅をタップしてみてください。

参考:
https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/4027871/windows-10-touchpad-gestures